# get current random seed from lua

Tags: random, lua

I know that you can set the seed of lua's random number generator with `math.randomseed()`.

I want to generate two separate deterministic sequences of numbers somewhat in parallel. I have reduced my problem to something to the effect of this:

```
-- assume seed1 and seed2 exist and are positive integers.
local sequence1 = {};
local sequence2 = {};

math.randomseed(seed1);
for i = 1,50 do
    sequence1[#sequence1 + 1] = math.random();
end
seed1 = math.getseed(); -- This is the function that I want.

-- stuff

math.randomseed(seed2);
for i = 1,75 do
    sequence2[#sequence2 + 1] = math.random();
end
seed2 = math.getseed(); -- This is the function that I want.

-- stuff


math.randomseed(seed1);
for i = 1,50 do
    sequence1[#sequence1 + 1] = math.random();
end
seed1 = math.getseed(); -- This is the function that I want.
```

I have looked through the documentation and thrown the `math` table into a `k,v in pairs` for loop and nothing has come up.
Does any such function exist in lua, or must I write my own generator for this purpose?

Comment: You have to write your own generator

Comment: if the total number of random numbers that you want to use is relatively small (e.g. 10,000 or fewer) you could just precompute two random arrays each with their own deterministic seed and then just pull from them as needed.

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't know how many from each seed I will need. It could be as small as 100 or as large as a million or more.

Comment: Just do your own generators then. A basic linear congruential one is just a few lines of code.

Comment: If you're rolling your own and use Lua 5.3 (which has 64-bit int binary operations), consider using [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/) instead of LCG. It's ~2-3 lines more code but gives _much_ better output.

Comment: 2 Sebastian: Have a look at an example of [PRNG](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/375ffe05075063c9a2ce61bb30b1ce50) suitable for all Lua versions (thanks to @nobody for the link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no functions in the standard Lua library that get the current seed.  To do this you would either need to:

1. Write your own RNG function (**difficult**)
2. Alter the `math.randomseed` function written in C (**risky**)
3. Use a RNG lib that has this feature (**simple**)
4. Save the number of times `math.random` is called to a variable (**simplest but not ideal**)

---

## Custom RNG

Writing your own RNG would be time consuming, prone to error, and not optimized.  You can search for algorithms on how to do this online, but they will each have their different quirks.  Some trade performance for randomness, while others random number patterns are potentially predictable.

---

## Alter `math.randomseed` in the standard library

Doing this *could potentially* jeopardize any 3rd party modules or libraries that use the `math` library.  Not to mention this could cause problems with Lua itself if you don't know what you are doing.

---

## Load a RNG

There are multiple RNG modules written in Lua available.  I'd strongly advise you to select one that suits your needs and make sure it is capable of getting the current seed.  [rotLove](https://github.com/paulofmandown/rotLove) has multiple ones that do this, but there is a caveat to using them.  The RNG seed you set for one of the modules **will not** seed `math.randomseed`.

[A relevant story on this...](https://github.com/paulofmandown/rotLove/issues/14)

This problem recently happened to someone who tried to use both a RNG from rotLove and a dice module I had developed.  The dice used `math.random` to determine rolls.  The person had set the seed with `RNG.randomseed` and assumed it would affect all `math.random` operations only to find that every runtime of their application yielded the same dice results.  This was because they never set `math.randomseed`!  Because of this I added my dice module to rotLove so that it would use the RNGs provided to generate dice rolls, instead of having to juggle a third party RNG and the default Lua RNG.

---

## Store a variable

After you set the seed, every time `math.random` is called increase the variable by +1.  When you need to get the seed just,

```
math.randomseed(orginal_seed_provided)
seed_counter = 0  -- every time math.random is called add one
-- whenever you need the current seed, it's the seed_counter

-- run code
-- suddenly you need to reset RNG to a previous seed

math.randomseed(orginal_seed_provided)
for i=1, seed_counter do 
  math.random() -- discarding the results from prior math.random operations 
end  
-- next call to math.random() will be where seed left off
```

This option has *dire consequences* because the more you use `math.random()` the more function calls you have to make to get to a seed that is buried.

Once you are getting a seed after `math.random` has been called 100,000+ times **it will be a CPU drain with noticeable effect so BEWARE.**