# Using different math.random() and math.randomseed() arguments for x, y, z components of Perlin Noise in Lua

Tags: lua

I've been working with an [adaptation](https://github.com/eyeofparadox/ff_lua_scripts/blob/main/ff_api_3d_perlin_sphere_map_v.1.0.lua) of [Perlin Noise in Lua](https://gist.github.com/kymckay/25758d37f8e3872e1636d90ad41fe2ed) for use in Filter Forge, specifically as spherically mapped and projected noise. I generate several channels of noise (ex. RGB or Offset, Distortion and Scale) and need each noise channel to be unique. Is it possible to modify the code I cited to call on a different seed for each noise channel? If so, how and where would I need to make those changes?

Comment: This isn't possible in plain Lua, for the reasons described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439422/get-current-random-seed-from-lua.

Comment: To clarify a little, I need six different perlin noise instances, and they could all come from the same initial seed if they were offset by a degree sufficient to avoid moire artifacts. I could say I need a 6-dimensional Perlin noise, but it's hard to visualize how that works in principle. Angle offsets work on a sphere, but I'm not sure how to apply them to a polar-to-cartesian mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out a solution by returning to the simple method of using offsets to address different regions of the existing noise. The trick was figuring out where to put the offsets to get the correct results.

My current script is posted [here](https://github.com/eyeofparadox/ff_lua_scripts/blob/main/ff_api_3d_perlin_sphere_map_v.1.0.1.lua) for reference. It's been cleaned up a bit as I went along, but evidence of my trial-and-error approach remains in the comments. A final version will be available to Filter Forge users through the Library, once the map script is used in an actual filter.